# how to built a xml file in drawable folder in android studio

Tags: android-studio, drawable

I'm using the Android Studio of 1.51 version,I don't know how to built a xml file in the drawable folder.When I clicked right button I found a XML selecton at the bottom,but it only can be used to build layout xml file or Values xml file.THX

Comment: Where is the problem? Just create a file in the folder drawable.

Comment: I have solved this problem,but thank u all the same